# Django interaction with html

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

Hi there i was learning how to use Django when i reach a tutorial,where the person call variable of other files(views.py) with this `{{}}`.
Can some explain how this html interacts with the views.oy file.
A code example could be this one:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html'%}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col_md_6">
        <div class="card card-body">

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <!-- Esto es una manera de mandar datos de manera segura -->
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{formset}}
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Why i can make references like **{{formset}}**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Django framework we use a data context to store the data that we want to send the template (.html)
after that we can access to the value using the delimeters {{}}

Ex:
views.py

```
def your_view_name(request):
    value = 12443
    context = {
        'template_var_name': value,
    }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)
```

in your_template.html:

you can access to the values using the name you defined in that context dict

```
<div>
    template_var_name is <strong>{{template_var_name}}</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses a custom templating engine that fills in variables and other things in html code when {{}} is used. I suggest you read [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#:~:text=A%20Django%20template%20is%20a,interpreted%20by%20the%20template%20engine.&text=A%20template%20is%20rendered%20with,the%20context%2C%20and%20executes%20tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#:%7E:text=A%20Django%20template%20is%20a,interpreted%20by%20the%20template%20engine.&text=A%20template%20is%20rendered%20with,the%20context%2C%20and%20executes%20tags). which goes more in depth.